# How to change the alias of a key within a keystore?

Tags: java, maven-2, java-web-start, jar-signing

I signed my JWS application [MemorizEasy](http://memorizeasy.mysimpatico.com) with a key whose alias is:

```
memofile.reference.emma.jar=/Users/simpatico/.netbeans/6.8/modules/ext/emma.jar
```

I don't remember why I chose such a long alias. I suspect it was memo only, but in my project settings I have:

```
jnlp.signjar.alias=memofile.reference.emma.jar=/Users/simpatico/.netbeans/6.8/modules/ext/emma.jar
```

I'm now updating the application and using maven I need to specify the alias as:

```
<keystorealias>memofile.reference.emma.jar=/Users/simpatico/.netbeans/6.8/modules/ext/emma.jar
</keystorealias>
```

Yet that doesn't work. Trying another key with alias `mjee` it works.

So could I change the alias of the key? If so, how?
Otherwise, why wouldn't Maven accept my alias?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

It is possible to duplicate a key in a keystore with the `keyclone` command of `keytool`:

```
keytool -keyclone -alias "your-very-very-long-alias" -dest "new-alias" -keypass keypass -new new_keypass -keystore /path/to/keystore -storepass storepass
```

The `changealias` command changes the alias for an existing entry:

```
keytool -changealias -alias "your-very-very-long-alias" -destalias "new-alias" -keypass keypass -keystore /path/to/keystore -storepass storepass
```

For those that want to be prompted to enter password just remove the respective password flags (`changealias` example):

```
keytool -changealias -alias "your-very-very-long-alias" -destalias "new-alias" -keystore "/path/to/keystore"
```

Comment: keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

I get the message above.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe your keystore file has been tampered with. Any other enclosed exception which could give us an idea of the cause?

Comment: I found this one to be "easier" because you don't need to enter your passwords directly but will be prompted to do so after the command: keytool -changealias -keystore my_keystore.jks -alias OLD_ALIAS -destalias NEW_ALIAS

Comment: I was able to run keytool on windows 10 by running it in [bash/windows subsystem for linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

Comment: java has keytool, no need to refer to bash... you can run it from cmd as far as you have added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your PATH. Double check with `where keytool` first.

Comment: Not working "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Comment: For an existing keystore file, is it possible to add a new key-alias and key-password for it, in addition to what's there?