# How can I find and run the keytool

Tags: android, windows, facebook, keytool

I am reading an development guide of Facebook Developers at [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android.)

It says that I must use keytool to export the signature for my app such as:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I do not know how to find the keytool in order to run it. I tried to open a Windows command prompt and paste the above command, but it did not work.

Comment: if you are running Linux based system `/usr/local/java/bin# ./keytool`
if you are running Windows `find the JDK install path and check bin folder`

Comment: i found this ansour you can use it to solve the prob
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390582/13405428

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I found a solution by myself as below quote. It works fine.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias
> sociallisting -keystore "D:\keystore\SocialListing"  |
> "C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\cygwin\bin\openssl.exe"
> base64
```

Comment: I found it here: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\keytool.exe

Comment: Or C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Comment: Thanks @SHAHM: great for us folks that don't want to explicitly download Java AGAIN and be bugged every week to upgrade to latest version.

Comment: I found that only `keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore` worked for me. Found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) from Google :)

Comment: For the "found it here" @JaimeMontoya comment as an addition. Add the directory for keytool.exe to your PATH. It'll make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 140):

Simply enter these into Windows command prompt.

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\userName\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

The base password is `android`

You will be presented with the `MD5`, `SHA1`, and `SHA256` keys; Choose the one you need.

Comment: this worked for me. For debug keys use the -alias androiddebugkey.

Comment: I use for the release version next line: 1) cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
 and next 2) keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\AndroidProjects\Project1\app\myapp.keystore"

Comment: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.`

Answer (score 80):

**To get android key hash code follow these steps (for facebook apps)**

1. Download the openssl for windows [here](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=)
2. now unzip to c drive
3. open cmd prompt
4. type `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin`
5. then type only `keytool -export -alias myAlias -keystore C:\Users\<your user name>\.android\myKeyStore | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl enc -a -e`
6. Done

**To get Certificate fingerprint(MD5) code follow these steps**

1. go to - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
2. inside the bin folder run the `jarsigner.exe` file
3. open cmd prompt
4. type `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin`
5. then again type on cmd `keytool -list -keystore "C:/Documents and Settings/<your user name>/.android/debug.keystore"`
6. it will ask for Keystore password now. The default is "`android`" type and enter
7. Done.

Comment: This worked for me up until the final step. After typing in "android" it spits out garbage... my guess is it isn't using the proper encoding? If I enter in something like "blah", it tells me the password was incorrect. So it knows I have the password correct when I type in "android"

Comment: I found the issue was I had left off the flags -list and -v

Answer (score 31):

keytool is part of the JDK.

Try to prepend `%{JAVA_HOME}\` to the exec statement or `c:\{path to jdk}\bin`.

Comment: I put the cer file and truststore file in the same directory and used this command: `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -keystore truststore -file certificate.cer -alias my-alias`

Answer (score 22):

I found this on another post, which did not get many upvotes, but it was super helpful for me. So will add it here.

**Android Studio** will bring a keytool with it.

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`

You can see his post below by Richar Heap, with a helpful reference. I did see this before but forgot about it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524526/4446406

Answer (score 13):

The KeyTool is part of the JDK. You'll find it, assuming you installed the JDK with default settings, in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 11):

`Robby Pond`'s answer can be generalized to use `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and to also compensate for any blanks that might occur in the path (like `Program Files`):

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 6):

keytool is part of jdk, it should be $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool

Answer (score 5):

keytool is located in JDK bin directory ($JAVA_HOME/bin). JAVA_HOME is your JDK installation directory.
To use that command line you should also include $JAVA_HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

Keytool is part of the Java SDK. You should be able to find it in your Java SDK directory e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin

Answer (score 4):

On cmd window (need to run as Administrator),

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%
```

only works if you have set up your system environment variable JAVA_HOME . To set up your system variable for your path, you can do this

```
setx %JAVA_HOME% C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\
```

Then, you can type

```
cd c:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin
```

or

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Then, execute any commands provided by JAVA jdk's, such as

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myapp
```

You just have to answer the questions (equivalent to typing the values on cmd line) after hitting enter! The key would be generated

Answer (score 3):

[Android: where to run keytool command in android](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-where-to-run-keytool-command-in.html)

Keytool command can be run at your dos command prompt, if JRE has been set in your  classpath variable.

For example, if you want to get the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate for android,

just run the following command...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\.android>  keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

where `C:\Documents and Settings\user\.android>` is the path which contains the `debug.keystore` that has to be certified.

For detailed information, please visit http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version of Eclipse ( I am using Kepler).
Go to Windows> Preferences>Android> Build.

You'll find the location path of your debug keystore as well as the SHA1 fingerprint (which you can just copy and use)

Answer (score 3):

If you installed visual studio with Xamarin/mobile development support, you'll have a java install here `C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_{version}\bin\`, as was my case.

Answer (score 2):

KEYTOOL is in JAVAC SDK .So you must find it in inside the directory that contaijns **javac**

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Gareth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4446406/gareth)

answer above, the below worked for me

Simply enter these into Windows command prompt.

Make sure the terminal is run as adminstrator

1. cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
2. keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\admin.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Read [more](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+find+out+sha+certificate+fingerprint+in+flutter)

N:B: This should be done after the first build, as the keys are only generated after first build

Answer (score 1):

`keytool` comes with the JDK. If you are using cygwin then this is probably on your path already. Otherwise, you might dig around in your JDK's bin folder.

You'll probably need to use cygwin anyways for the shell pipes (`|`) to work.

Comment: Could you tell me how to run below command?
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

Comment: Yes, I did. and when I run above command, the CMD say: 'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You probably need to install the openssl package as well via cygwin's setup.

Comment: I installed openssl package already. The problem still occurs :(

Comment: Can you run openssl by itself? What options do you see when you type "open" and press tab?

Comment: I installed cygwin as well as openssl already. But I don't know how to run them. I just run windows command line (cmd) and type the command.

Comment: You have to access the cygwin shell. Installing cygwin should've made a shortcut on your desktop for it.

Answer (score 1):

Few observations while I was getting the same problem (Windows). 
 1. Shell pipe is important.
 2. If you are using OpenSSL or Cygwin, definitely you have to install it.
 3. keytool comes with JDK so either you have to point to it in the command or you have cd to the JDK/bin folder (where the exe resides)
 4. The debug keystore is typically located at ~/.android/debug.keystore 
 5. password is "android" whether you -keypass it or type it when prompted.
 6. For the alias name, you can open (DO NOT SAVE, just open and close) the keystore file with any editor and read it.
 7. MOST IMPORTANT - There is a difference is specifying the keystore path within quotes and without. I got it working by using the keystore path within the double quotes. 
As remix090378 said and as per the [instruction](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api), this command indeed worked -
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\userName.android\debug.keystore" -list -v

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do the following :

- copy the bat file below in any folder already present in your `PATH` environment variable
- then simply use `keytool` command in any Windows shell

Actual location of keytool is defined in the bat file. In case the location is wrong the bat file will scan your system to detect potential locations in ProgramFiles (sub)folders.

Also find keytool2.bat, a convinient shortcut for "keytool -v -list -keystore", which is widely used to quickly check the content of a jks file.

keytool.bat :

---

```
:: 
:: 
:: "keytool alias" script by Céphas
:: easy method : add the known keytool.exe folder to your personal PATH variable (run : C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables)
:: else, add the folder containing this bat script to your personal path or put this script in any folder already defined in your path
::
:: also see keytool2.bat that automatically adds the following parameters in the keytool command line : -v -list -keystore, for quick display of jks content
:: 
:: 
@echo off
set THIS_SCRIPT=%~f0
rem  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion : necessary for paths containing special chars
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem  set PATH to keytool.exe ; path must include the final \
rem  ^ is escape char for paths containing & \ < > ^ | 
set PATH_TO=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\
set PROG_NAME=keytool.exe

rem full_path, with "", to work with paths containing special chars
set FULL_KT_PATH="!PATH_TO!!PROG_NAME!"

rem checks if keytool.exe exists
(dir %FULL_KT_PATH%>nul 2>nul && set KT_FOUND=yes) || set KT_FOUND=no

if %KT_FOUND%==yes (
    rem keytool found => launching it with all supplied parameters
    rem 
    rem
    %FULL_KT_PATH% %*
    rem
    rem
) else (
    rem keytool not found, trying to find it in %ProgramFiles%

    echo.
    echo Keytool not found in expected location, scan in progess ...
    echo.

    cd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" 2>nul && dir /B /S keytool.exe 2>nul

    cd "%ProgramFiles%" 2>nul && dir /B /S keytool.exe 2>nul

    echo.
    echo *********
    echo Path to program keytool.exe not properly defined, or keytool/java missing on this system
    echo If any location has been found during above scan, fix variable "PATH_TO" in %THIS_SCRIPT% accordingly
    echo *********
    echo.
    pause
    
)
```

---

keytool2.bat :

---

```
:: 
:: 
:: "keytool2 alias" script by Céphas
:: easy method : add the known keytool.exe folder to your personal PATH variable (run : C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables)
:: else, add the folder containing this bat script to your personal path or put this script in any folder already defined in your path
::
:: keytool2 automatically adds the following parameters in the keytool command line : -v -list -keystore
:: thus, to quickly display the full content of a jks file, usage is simply : keytool2 \path\to\your\keystore.jks [-alias your_alias]
:: 
:: 
@echo off
set THIS_SCRIPT=%~f0
rem  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion : necessary for paths containing special chars
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem  set PATH to keytool.exe ; path must include the final \
rem  ^ is escape char for paths containing & \ < > ^ | 
set PATH_TO=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\
set PROG_NAME=keytool.exe


rem full_path, with "", to work with paths containing special chars
set FULL_KT_PATH="!PATH_TO!!PROG_NAME!"

rem checks if keytool.exe exists
(dir %FULL_KT_PATH%>nul 2>nul && set KT_FOUND=yes) || set KT_FOUND=no

if %KT_FOUND%==yes (
    rem keytool found => launching it with all supplied parameters
    rem 
    rem
    %FULL_KT_PATH% -v -list -keystore %*
    rem
    rem
) else (
    rem keytool not found, trying to find it in %ProgramFiles%

    echo.
    echo Keytool not found in expected location, scan in progess ...
    echo.

    cd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" 2>nul && dir /B /S keytool.exe 2>nul

    cd "%ProgramFiles%" 2>nul && dir /B /S keytool.exe 2>nul

    echo.
    echo *********
    echo Path to program keytool.exe not properly defined, or keytool/java missing on this system
    echo If any location has been found during above scan, fix variable "PATH_TO" in %THIS_SCRIPT% accordingly
    echo *********
    echo.
    pause
    
)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

On Windows

If your using Jetbrain's Toolbox, to manage Android Studio update, the path is something like

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\202.7486908\jre\bin
```

*After an update I have to manually update/set this path as `JAVA_HOME` (the jre folder)*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had already generated an APK file using the command `ionic cordova build android --prod` and I needed to get the SHA-1 fingerprint for the already existing APK file. Here's how I got it by running the following command in the App directory:

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk`

So, I basically ran the above command in the following app location:

`C:\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug>keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk`

This gave me the SHA1 fingerprint as: `7B:6B:AD:...`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding PATH as an Environment variable and access it via cmd.

PATH as the value and C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_331\bin as the variable and access it via keytool ...

Answer (score 0):

#Go to the path where cacerts or jsk is present and open and run below command on cmd

keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts

keytool -v -list -keystore .jks

Comment: User does not know how to find the keytool in order to run it. Please include that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity and have not installed java or android studio none of the paths mentioned will work.

Unity installs a copy of the jre keytool inside each of it's editor folders.

You can use unity hub to open the location of the editor version you are using and fromt here
open:
`Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\jre\bin`.

For example my exact path is: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\jre\bin

Then just open a terminal in that location and run it from there. If on windows you might have to type `keytool.exe` no just `keytool` depending on what terminal/shell you use.

You could add it to your system path but its not nessisary and you might want to be able to change what version your using so I prefer to just use it as is.

Answer (score -1):

Given that you have **installed Java and preferably a JDK in your system** ( answering for Windows because you mentioned it in your question) you **should have the keytool utility on your installation's `bin` folder.**

If that's the case, what you can do next is **add that bin folder to the `PATH` environment variable** of your Windows installation.

The next time you will open a Windows shell and you'll type `keytool` you will be able to run the actual utility.