# can't get MD5 fingerprint from keytool command

Tags: google-maps, md5, keytool, fingerprint

I need the MD5 fingerprint to generate an API key for google maps. When I run the keytool command, I don't get the MD5 fingerprint. Instead I get the SHA1 fingerprint which is not what I want.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey 
-keystore C:\Users\Psiu\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
androiddebugkey, 26-Feb-2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FA:66:B5:2A:05:8D:6E:2D:AA:89:D0:7F:97:6D:8D:9D:3A:1F:64:A1
```

How do I get the MD5 fingerprint?

Comment: duplicate of [How can I find and run the keytool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `-v` option to your `keytool` command and the tool will list all the different algorithms supported and you will get the SHA1 and MD5 listed.

For e.g. `keytool -v -list [...rest of your command]`