# Obtain sha1 key

Tags: android, api, key

In android I have try to obtain a google apikey version 2 , 
I tried to obtain the sha 1 key as follows  keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\sapu.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android but in command prompt keytool is not recogenize as internal or external command how can I overcome this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this happens because the Java home is not in your Path. Add the full path to the jdk folder to the Path variable and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the command `keytool` stored? Is it in your path? If not, then you need to give the full path.

More instructions can be found at [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)