# Google Map Doesn't Show Anything

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm using a `MapFragment` to display a google map.
I think I have everything done right in code but map doesn't show anything[image]
I guess it's API Key issue.

this is how I got it:

Used this command to generate `SHA1 Fingerprint`:
`keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/[USERNAME]/[debug.keystore path] -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Created new project in Google developer console, enabled Google Maps Api V2, created new Android Key in Credentials

This is my project credentials from google developer console:
[image]

and this is `Manifest` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="erpus.distribution" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application android:label="ERPus.Distribution"></application>
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyA14yRAzOpkXeHD86MzZbqglUlM8DxSS-I" />
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <permission android:name="erpus.distribution.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="erpus.distribution.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</manifest>
```

Any Suggestions?

**Edit:**
I'm writing on Xamarin. Here's My fragment if anyone needs it:

```
public class ContractorMapFragment : Fragment {
    View view;
    private static int layoutId;

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
        GoogleMap Map = mapFrag.Map;
        if (Map != null) {
            Map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
            Map.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
            Map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view.Parent;
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.RemoveView(view);
            }
        }

        try {
            if (layoutId == 0)
                layoutId = Resource.Layout.MapFragmentLayout;
            view = inflater.Inflate(layoutId, container, false);
        }
        catch (InflateException e) {

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

And View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: If your map not showing while you run your release mode apk??

Comment: @PiyushGupta sorry I didn't really understand what you asked. I'm running it on debug mode.

Comment: Check your SHA finger print and ur API key must be right.

Comment: Try to add browser key and check if it works if it does then the problem is with the SHA (don't release the apk with the browser key)

Comment: @meh still nothing. anyway why would browser key work on android?

Comment: No. you need to use Android Key!

Comment: If you generate a signed apk, notice that you must debug/run your app with the same debug.keystore that you have used to generate your SHA finger print

Comment: @PiyushGupta I'm using Android Key. what else can I try?

Comment: I had same issue when i created map api key from one machine and i was running my application from different machine.

Comment: @misho Must be sure its only because of different SHA. So have yu created API key some other PC and copy source code to another machine and run the app??

Comment: @Rami I'm just deploying the app to my Nexus device.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, i did this before but then created new `api key` from the pc I'm using right now.

Comment: @misho Have you created keystore file for your app?

Comment: @PiyushGupta no, do I need it on debug mode?

Comment: It seems that you have problem in your fragment code.
Give us .java code.

Comment: @Anatol I'm writing on Xamarin with C#. I can post it if you wish

Comment: @misho oh. Sorry. i Can't help you so.
But you really should do this for other participants.

Comment: @Anatol thanks anyways but still, I strongly doubt that there's something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin is using a different debug.keystore!

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
CMD says `'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.
Am I pasting the command correctly?
http://i.imgur.com/untqNrW.png

Comment: For Windows users you have to install openssl for the command line (probably through cygwin. Please check this response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7201252/1117968

Comment: I've installed openssl and I'm not getting any errors, but this thing doens't look like a SHA1 fingerprint
http://i.imgur.com/Qp26eNh.jpg

any suggestions?

Comment: That is a base64 encoded version of a binary encoded sha1

Comment: If you want to see just the shah run keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1

Comment: Thanks again for your attention.
This is what I got so far: http://i.imgur.com/lr6XA8S.png

Sorry for asking too much questions but i really need to get this done.
Thanks again

Comment: Insert a colon after every other character and capitalize all lower case letters maybe?

Comment: That worked, google dev. console generated new api key. I haven't tested it yet but I think there's nothing else to ask.
Thanks for your help!