# But I do not have ---> Key Alias , I ask what is the solution

Tags: android, android-studio, alias, keystore

I want to update application to Android Studio
I own Key password
I own Keystor path
But I do not have ---> Key Alias

I ask what is the solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVpui.png)

Comment: if you do not have ---> Key Alias. Then you cannot ---> Update app

Answer (score 0):

If you remember your key password than you can get key alias with following command

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore <store>
```

**But you need keystore password for this first.**

after executing this command you need to enter your key password and it will show your key alias.

[image]

[**How can I find and run the keytool**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)

Comment: keytool ?? Where can I get it

Comment: you can find it under Java->jdk->bin

Comment: When you press them appear and disappear