# Why google maps services isn't working after uploading app to Play Store?

Tags: android, google-maps

My Application is ready and it well worked before uploading it to Google Play Store.

After I've uploaded my app to the Play Store, the google maps services didn't work. The map is empty for some reason.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get Key for Release

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

For Linux or OS X, open a terminal window and enter the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore YOUR_KEY_PATH
```

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore YOUR_KEY_PATH
```

In my case, i'm using Linux and my command was:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/projects/keys/myapp.jks
```

And get the result

```
Alias name: ALIAS NAME
Creation date: Jan 01, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Release, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Release, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4aa9b300
Valid from: Mon Jan 01 08:04:04 UTC 2013 until: Mon Jan 01 18:04:04 PST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  AE:9F:95:D0:A6:86:89:BC:A8:70:BA:34:FF:6A:AC:F9
     SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

Comment: I didn't understand something. Where to write this line?
keytool -list -v -keystore YOUR_KEY_PATH

I'm using windows 7

Comment: Keytool is a Java tool, you can find it following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736396/2697368

Comment: There is no error... I Type this in my "Run": keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\abab\Desktop\key.jks and it says that windows couldn't find "keytool"

Comment: where is your Java JDK path ? You need to join inside them to execute your command like cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin , but check your JDK version and correct instalation path..

Comment: Please, watch this tutorial to learn how to configure your Windows to keytool work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=extCL1UU5wk

Comment: Ok, Now, My Keytool is located here: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin

But in the cmd, It automtically writes C:\Users\user

What can I do?

Comment: Just do it: cd "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin" and then keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "c:\Users\abab\Desktop\key.jks"

Comment: Ok, I got the SHA1, what to do with it now?

Comment: Please, just read the documentation or tutorials on web ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=pt-br#etapa_3_criar_um_projeto_do_google_maps , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm )