# I need assistance with getting the release & debug certificate fingerprint

Tags: java, android, authentication, ssl, sha1

I'm working on an app that requires login with Google account. I got stuck at **release certificate fingerprint** and **debug certificate fingerprint**.

It says

> Open a terminal and run the keytool utility provided with Java to get
>   the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate. You should get both the
>   release and debug certificate fingerprints.
>
> To get the release certificate fingerprint:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

What I don't understand here is what my key name will be & where to get the `path-to-production-keystore`. Also when I type `keytool` in the Terminal of Android Studio, I get

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And to get the ***debug certificate fingerprint*** it says

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

What would be the `%USERPROFILE%\` here?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Its usually the user's home directory

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Try looking in `C:\Users\.android` or `C:\Documents and Settings\[User Name]\.android`

Comment: I tried the following command on the terminal of Android Studio 

`keytool -exportcert -list -v \-alias androidreleasekey -keystore C:\Users\AURO.android`

and I got the following error message

`'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Any solution??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool

Answer (score 0):

USERPROFILE woulb be your username on that machine

If your uername is "auro" then the command will be

-alias androiddebugkey -keystore auro\.android\debug.keystore

and the path of the file will be

C:\Users\auro.android

Comment: I tried the following command on the terminal of Android Studio 

`keytool -exportcert -list -v \-alias androidreleasekey -keystore C:\Users\AURO.android`

and I got the following error message

`'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Any solution??