# Google Sign In trouble after using baseGameUtils Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, google-signin, basegameutils

After extending BaseGameActivity on MainActivity, when you open the game it shows the animation of connecting to Google Play Games but at the end shows the message Failed to sign in. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) that describes how to troubleshoot issues that you might encounter while developing Android games with the Play Games SDK.

> If you are unable to sign players into your game, first make sure that you have followed the instructions to [create your client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [configure the games services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring).

If you still encounter sign-in errors, check the following items to make sure that your game is set up correctly.

- [Check your metadata tags](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags)
- [Check your package name](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_package_name)
- [Check the certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_the_certificate_fingerprint)
- [Check that test accounts are enabled](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_that_test_accounts_are_enabled)

If you are using Proguard and are seeing errors on the obfuscated APK, check the target API level on your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Make sure to set it to 17 or above.

Here's another reference which might also help: [Google Play Services fails to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677245/google-play-services-fails-to-connect)

Comment: After a day i am able to find out maybe the reason of the error might be this  "You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE."