# Android: cannot update my application at Play store

Tags: android, android-update-app

While I am trying to to update my Application at play Store I am receiving message:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 89:2F:11:FE:CE:D6:CC:DF:65:E7:76:3E:DD:A7:96:4F:84:DD:BA:33 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 20:26:F4:C1:DF:0F:2B:D9:46:03:FF:AB:07:B1:28:7B:9C:75:44:CC ]
```

I have searched everything but couldn't get a solution and I have also checked the following things:

1. **Private Key  and store key for both old and new version**
2. **Package Name is same for both old and new version**
3. **Updated the version and name in manifest plus gradle**

If any one has a solution let me know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Updating the Application Things must be kept in mind:

1. **Same Package name of old and new app**.
2. **Same Store Key for old and new app**
3. **Update the version name and version code of new in manifest file**.

For Android Studio:

Go to **Tools/BuildApk**

Select **Choose Existing** and Select path of your **KeyStore**.

Enter **Password**

Enter "**Alias** **Name** **"**

Enter "**Alias Password**"

And Select Next

and then Select **release**

and click Finish

Answer (score 2):

make sure your keystore to sign previous app version is the same keystore you used to sign the apk you want to upload in play store.

Comment: i am using same keystore, while i updating i forgot the alias key so what to do now?

Comment: @KumailHussain You need to use the same certificate within the keystore

Comment: @ Doomsknight means the alias should be same while updating?

Comment: @KumailHussain Yes

Comment: @Doomsknight what if i make a new alias will it update ??or give me the same error?

Comment: you can use command `keytool -list -keystore <your-key-store>` to check alias inside your keystore

Comment: if i create a new one for the app  using same store key will it update?

Comment: no, I don't think it possible to update with different key

Comment: @hakim how can i use key tool in android studion or any other method

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool . keytool is part of jdk, you can run it in terminal (if you are using mac) or Windows's command prompt

Comment: @hakim ...Thanks Man For Help :)