# Creating release key Android

Tags: android, keytool

I am trying to generate a signed key for the Spotify Api.I am having a little trouble understanding a few small things.

In there instructions:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/

It has:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH> -list -v | grep SHA1
```

So I have found the keytool and got that to run but I am getting an unauthorised error.

I had it as:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <my_key_alias> -keystore <C:\Users\MyComputer\AndroidStudioProjects\KeyStore> -list -v | grep SHA1
```

I want to confirm exactly what I need to do.

Is RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PATH the directory or the actual name of a file?

And I assume in the way the have syntaxed RELEASE_KEYSTORE they are using an environment variable not just a place holder?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems everything is ok except adding this to the path "...\release.keystore"

Comment: @uguboz thanks for your response. When I did that it said the system cannot find the file specified. Do you have to create the file first?

Comment: Did you do "Build - > Generate Signed Apk" to generate a release apk first?

Comment: No i didn't realise I needed to. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: btw i m wrong with first comment it will generate .jks keystore file where u pointed out instead of .keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using there documentation. (I did notice I was trying to do the realease key when I only needed the debug key) but this is how I ended up doing it.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\userName\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

I got that from this question here:

[How can I find and run the keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)

Hope this helps someone