# How to change file java.exe to keytool.exe so i can create signed apk for flutter?

Tags: flutter, keystore, keytool

Hi i am currently trying to create a signed apk for a flutter app but I've encounter a problem. Based on official docs https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android " Note: The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of the Java JDK, which is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run flutter doctor -v and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’. Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with keytool." and ive check and thats really my situation, now my question is how can i change the location "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java" to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool". Thanks for any answer coz i have already search how exactly to do that but failed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: Simply enter these into Windows command prompt.
*italic* **bold** `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`

following: [How can I find and run the keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)

Comment: yup thanks they can also run the command there, In my case Im using a visual studio and i just run the command on the terminal, Its just the i forgot to change the path name

Comment: @DavidB.   Don't forget to 'accept' and/or 'upvote' answers on SO that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Dude I actually solved it my own, I just read the https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android again it seams that I didnt change the `keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:/Users/USER_NAME/key.jks` (<-This is the problem, there is no path on my PC with that name, so just change it) `-storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`

To solved this issue:

Use this command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:/Users/USER_NAME/key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key` and change the **c:/Users/USER_NAME/** with an actual directory.