# 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have run this command keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:/Users/USER_NAME/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key.  I got this in my Terminal 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. How can I  resolve this error?

Comment: you need to follow this steps [This will Help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)

Answer (score 0):

keytool is not on the PATH of your OS. You can put keytool on the PATH and run again or execute directly from the folder where it is in (generally is the folder of your jdk)

Answer (score 0):

keytool is part of jdk, it should be $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool . make sure to find it in your environment variables