# keytool is missing from its jre/bin folder

Tags: android-studio, keytool

I would like to use `keytool`.

As usually - as far as I know - its default install place with Android Studio is the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

Well, my folder is empty as you can see:

[image]

I have reinstalled Android Studio twice and this folder still contains nothing.

Any insights?

**EDIT:**

I've installed it for the third time, and now there is not even a "jre" folder inside the "Android Studio" folder:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with the exact same thing for days with no answers or no one else posting that they had the same struggle

My keytool was in the jbr/bin folder.
Call to that folderpath when using keytool in the cmd prompt (ala this page [How can I find and run the keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)) -but in your case it should be something like:

C:\Users[name]>C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey .....

also; adding the path in the system environment variable did nothing for me, i had to manually type in the path in the prompt as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

My keytool is inside the bin of jbr too. Try use dot operator:

```
. "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\keytool.exe" -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

This way, you don't have to set path.