# Can I sign JAR files using existing certificate in certificate store?

Tags: java, certificate, code-signing, keytool, jarsigner

I have a code signing certificate that is installed in my MMC Certificates Snapin in Windows.

When signing exes I use a command like this:

```
signtool sign /v /sm /s my /n "NAME_ISSUED_TO" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll
```

This locates the correct certificate from my certificate store and signs the exe without needing the pfx file on disk.

Is there a way to do something similar with Java?

I have had it working with [these instructions](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1072) but this requires a pfx file on disk.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

Using the steps outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714112/101642) answer, I managed to import the pfx file into my keystore.

Then it was a case of omitting the keystore flag from [these instructions](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1072).

Hope this helps others in the same situation.

Alan