# Why it my certificate not enabled on jboss 4.2 on https?

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, jboss-4.2.x

I need to add a valid certificate to my website.

I have added the following commands

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe"  -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe" -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file root.cer -keystore keystore.jks
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\keytool.exe" -certreq -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file kvv.cer
```

And i have added the following configuration to my server.xml as mentioned here: http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/jboss-tutorial-how-to-enable-ssl-https-on-jboss-as-well-as-other-nice-to-know-configurations/

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/keystore.jks"
              keystorePass="keystore"
              truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/keystore.jks" 
              truststorePass="keystore"
              strategy="ms" 
              address="${jboss.bind.address}"
              />
```

But when i go to my website on localhost i still get an invalid certificate.

What have i done wrong?

I use jboss 4.2

Thanks

Comment: and where have you executed these commands at ? I mean the directory where you executed these

Comment: on my desktop, but after executing the commands i have copied the keystore.jks file to ${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/ directory

Comment: if I may, could you run the commands while in conf dir itself

Comment: Still the same problem...

Comment: shouldn't this be the conf : <Connector port="THE_PORT_YOU_LIKE" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false"
          strategy="ms"
              address="${jboss.bind.address}"
              keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/THE_KEYSTORE_NAME"
              keystorePass="PASSWORD_FOR_THE_KEYSTORE"
              truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/THE_KEYSTORE_NAME"
              truststorePass="PASSWORD_FOR_THE_KEYSTORE"
              sslProtocol="TLS"/>

Comment: Still the same error (i have updated the connector properties in the question above).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was working with the public certificate. When I imported my private certificate as explained here: [How to convert .pfx file to keystore with private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217107/how-to-convert-pfx-file-to-keystore-with-private-key) it worked as expected!