# Configure Firefox for client-side SSL authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, openssl, keytool

I followed the instructions from

http://www.maximporges.com/2009/11/18/configuring-tomcat-ssl-clientserver-authentication/

And got a tomcat server working with two-sided authentication.

I tested this worked with the Java Client that is included in that blog post.

I then moved to access it from either chrome or firefox.

After some time, I figured I needed to convert some of the certificates from pks to pkcs12.  I used this source

[How to convert .pfx file to keystore with private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217107/how-to-convert-pfx-file-to-keystore-with-private-key)

So now I have Firefox with both the server certificate and the client pkcs12.  However, I just get this:

�

Chrome does not accept any server cerficate format I throw at it.  Although it accepted the client pcks12 certificate.  Having Firefox work would be enough.

What I am I missing ?

What should I use to get more information on what is going wrong ?

�

Is the same thing I got when firefox had no certificates registered.

Comment: That link for '.pfx file to keystore' is showing JKS to PKCS12.  `keytool` has a weakness in converting JKS to PKCS12 files for some reason.  It ends up discarding the private key.  Can you check the PKCS12 file and see if it is missing the private key?  If so, I'll try to get you the code for a program that works.

Comment: Ah, strike that - it was the other way around.  Keytool may be fine for JKS -> PKCS12.  Just not for PKCS12 -> JKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an 's'

https://[server address]...

instead of

http://

Details !