# Sign Android apk with pfx that will be valid until 2033?

Tags: android, apk, code-signing, keytool, pfx

I'm trying to sign my Android *.apk* using our company's code signing certificate that's in a *.pfx*. I'm able to convert the *.pfx* to a *.jks* fine (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217107/how-to-convert-pfx-file-to-keystore-with-private-key)) and can sign the *.apk* with it, but I saw from the [Android publishing guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) that the certificate should be valid until **22 October 2033**. However, our code signing cert expires in 2 years.

So, is it possible to sign an *.apk* using a Java keystore (*.jks*) that's converted from a *.pfx* and be valid until 2033?

Comment: The KEY is only valid for 2 years. You need to get a key that is valid for longer.

Comment: The reason you need a long lasting key is that you have to sign your apk using the same key every time you update.  Once your key expires, you will no longer be able to update your app.

Comment: @cyroxis So then it's not possible to use our code signing cert to sign the apk and be valid until 2033, correct?

Comment: @lonian316 Correct, my point is that a **signing** does not expire. When you sign an app with a key that build/version of the app is signed with that key forever. But a **key** (think secret password) has an expiration date, after which point you should no longer trust the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is it possible to sign an .apk using a Java keystore (.jks) that's converted from a .pfx and be valid until 2033?

You do not sign with keystore. You sign with key. And that key must expire no sooner than 22 Oct 2033. Since your expires sooner, you need new key to be able to sign your app.

Comment: It's not possible to buy a code signing cert that lasts for 17 years. I guess I will have to create a private key myself using keytool that's only used to sign the .apk, right?

Comment: You do not need to buy anything. Apps are signed using key you create yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Publishing code with a self created cert just seems foreign to me.