# how to import the .pfx file in java runtime environment?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, cer

Installing pfx in chrome is working fine, able to access the third party url..
what are steps to import pfx file in java application such that application can access the third party url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4714112/351861

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert .pfx file to keystore with private key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217107/how-to-convert-pfx-file-to-keystore-with-private-key)