# Duplicating a private key with a new alias

Tags: android, keytool, google-play, jarsigner

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

I have a keystore that I already have an alias and password for.

I have released applications using this keystore.

I have now given ownership of one of these applications to someone else, and so to update that application they need to use my keystore. However I don't want them to use my alias or password.

**Is it possible to create a new alias and password for the same keystore**

and just as importantly

**will Google Play allow an APK signed with the new alias to be used as an update** for that already published app?

If so what is the command, or a good help link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it, thanks @Rossco for the initial boost.

First I copied my keystore to a new file

```
ctrl+c ctrl+v
```

Then I changed the password on the keystore:

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```

Then I changed the name of the alias in the keystore

```
keytool -changealias -keystore my.keystore -alias "old_alias" -destalias "new_alias"
```

Then I changed the password for the new alias:

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore my.keystore -alias new_alias -keypass oldAliasPassword -new newAliasPassword
```

And yes I've just tested it and uploaded a new version of the app with the new keystore alias

Thanks!

References:

- [Keystore change passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords)
- [Can I change the alias of my key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483121/can-i-change-the-alias-of-my-key)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score 1):

Your key store contains your key. Just put your key in a new keystore. And give them that one. Or.. I suppose just give them the key.

Comment: Any url document references or how to's? How do you get the key out / put it in a new keystore?

Comment: keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore existing-store.jks -destkeystore new-store.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

Comment: Ok I had to use ` -deststoretype JKS` but that just clones the keystore, I need to add a new alias as well

Comment: keytool -export -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt