# How to change Key Alias Password for Android app?

Tags: android, alias, keytool

I published the first version of my app last year, and now I want to update that as I did before. But now I get an error like in

- [cannot-recover-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606837/cannot-recover-key)

  and I want to change my alias password. I tried these solution from the net:

  - [Can I change the alias of my key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483121)
  - [Cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606837)
  - [Android Studio: cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688)

But nothing helped me. `cmd` wants me to enter my **old password** every time and then replace it with new one, but I don't remember it. What can I do? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is you should remember the **old Password** buddy..!!

Comment: It's like changing your email password, you should have your old one to be able to login (here logging into keystore) and then changing your password to something new.

Comment: in those solutions everybody entered just one password !!