# Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: java, security, cryptography

So, I have written some code to take a PEM, add it to a PKCS keystore via bouncycastle, and then use java crypto to import the PKCS keystore value into a JKS keystore.

I swear that yesterday I had a unit test pass successfully having executed these steps, but this morning I started hitting this

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:181) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2039) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

Now, it's always possible something changed underneath me but I cannot figure out what it was.  It seems whatever provider I *was* using for that algorithm has since disappeared.

here's my java.security file snippet:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=apple.security.AppleProvider
```

There's not a whole lot to the code.  First I create a PKCS keystore via bouncycastle, adding a pem and saving to disk as PKCS12. Then import via java crypto, saving back out as JKS.

```
   public KeystoreBuilder createJksFromPem(String pemPrivate, String pemPublic, String alias) throws Exception
    {
        Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pemPrivate), "pemPrivate must not be empty");
        Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pemPublic), "pemPublic must not be empty");
        Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(alias), "alias must not be empty");

        String pkcsFilename = filename + ".pkcs";
        convertPemToPkcs(pemPrivate, pemPublic, pkcsFilename);

        importPkcsIntoJks(pkcsFilename);

        return this;
    }

    private void importPkcsIntoJks(String pkcsFilename) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore pkcs = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        File pkcsFile = new File(pkcsFilename);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pkcsFile))
        {
            pkcs.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
        }
        pkcsFile.delete();

        KeyStore jks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        jks.load(null);

        Enumeration<String> aliases = pkcs.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();
            if (!pkcs.isKeyEntry(alias))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Key key = pkcs.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] chain = pkcs.getCertificateChain(alias);

            jks.setKeyEntry(alias, key, password.toCharArray(), chain);
        }

        persist(jks);
    }

    private void convertPemToPkcs(String pemPrivate, String pemPublic, String pkcsFilename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, PKCSException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        X509CertificateHolder cert = (X509CertificateHolder) readObject(pemPublic);
        PEMKeyPair keyPair = (PEMKeyPair) readObject(pemPrivate);

        JcaX509ExtensionUtils extUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
        PKCS12SafeBagBuilder pkcs12BagBuilder = new PKCS12SafeBagBuilder(cert);
        pkcs12BagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_friendlyName, new DERBMPString("Kafka SSL Certificate"));
        pkcs12BagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_localKeyId, extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(keyPair.getPublicKeyInfo()));

        PKCS12PfxPduBuilder builder = new PKCS12PfxPduBuilder();

        builder.addData(pkcs12BagBuilder.build());

        builder.addEncryptedData(new JcePKCSPBEOutputEncryptorBuilder(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pbeWithSHAAnd128BitRC2_CBC).setProvider("BC").build(password.toCharArray()), pkcs12BagBuilder.build());

        PKCS12PfxPdu pfx = builder.build(new JcePKCS12MacCalculatorBuilder(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256), password.toCharArray());

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pkcsFilename)))
        {
            fos.write(pfx.getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DL));
        }
    }
```

and boom it blows up on

```
pkcs.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
```

As you can see, the BouncyCastleProvider was added explicitly. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Thanks dave_thompson_085 for the suggestion.  Can't believe I didn't see that overloaded method, but the solution was to specify the provider in the call get Keystore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC").

Comment: An internet search shows [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013493) could be related. Furthermore, I don't see the Bouncy Castle provider anywhere, maybe that will help?

Comment: Editing some code to replay the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Adding the BC provider doesn't give it priority; your stacktrace confirms you are getting the SunJSSE provider's implementation. Try using `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC")` or if you want to live dangerously **insert**ing the BC provider at or below position 4. Or just do the PB-MAC on the PKCS12 with SHA1 like everybody else -- you're already using it for the PBE. Plus it looks to me like you're strongly encryping the cert -- why??

Comment: aaaaahhhhhhh that fixed it, thanks dave_thompson_085!!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, which code specifically are you referring to WRT 'strongly encrypting'? the 'addEncryptedData()' call?

Comment: Adam: exactly. <! pad>

Comment: I just took it from here

https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/PKCS12PfxPduBuilder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as dave_thompson_085 pointed out, I can specify which provider I want to be used for the keystore.  I didn't realize this initially as I missed the getInstance() overload.

So in summary, calling this fixed my issue:

`KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC")`

too easy.

Answer (score 23):

Open Android Studio and go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Build Tools > Gradle`, then change Gradle JDK to jdk16, then click Sync Gradle.

And you can go to the build project without any error.

Comment: Using JDK 15 in android studio solves the problem. JDK 16 throws errors for some dependencies.

Comment: I'm using JDK16 solves the problem. My React app React work now.

Answer (score 6):

The `HmacPBESHA256` sounds like the algorithm to verify the integrity after decrypting the file. You can decrypt your Keystore and encrypt again, which may doesn't use the `HmacPBESHA256`.

---

In my case, I generate the key using the Windows tool (i.e "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider"). By default, the `pfx` uses `HmacPBESHA256`, which Java 11 doesn't support.

The solution is to create a new Keystore, but using `openssl`. In order to do that, I run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "your_keystore.pfx" -nodes | openssl pkcs12 -export -out "new_keystore.pfx"
```

That works on `jarsign`/`apksign`, by providing the `new_keystore.pfx` into as the keystore.

Comment: Thank you so much for this fix.  Note, in my case, it wiped out my `alias` value (changed it to `1`) and had to re-apply the alias using these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707518/3196753.

Oddly, testing the offending file using `keytool -list -v -keystore` as a baseline with Java 11.0.4, the HmacPBESHA256 error shows, but when I switched to 11.0.16, the error went away.   For compatibility reasons, I still went the extra mile to use the above openssl steps and now the file works with both versions.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be caused by older OpenJDK Java versions. (Keytool)

In my case this version solved the problem: openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18

Comment: Had same issue with 11.0.17 (from Oct/2022). A corretto 11.0.13_8 solved it for me. ( from Oct/2021)

Comment: I had this issue too. For me fixed with jdk 17

Comment: 11.0.20 fixed it for me .
11.0.20 was shown as the version in android studio, so I used that

Comment: Thank you. I migrated to OpenJDK 17 and now it works

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively the `HmacPBESHA256` algorithm is supported by standard java (SunJCE Provider) [starting from Java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-A47B1249-593C-4C38-A0D0-68FA7681E0A7).
I would use it like this:

```
//run with Java 12!
public void test() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Provider provider = java.security.Security.getProvider("SunJCE");
    System.out.println(provider.getName());
    Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacPBESHA256",provider);
    System.out.println(m.getAlgorithm());
}
```

Comment: I am using java version 16, But still getting error

Comment: But it is available if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-A47B1249-593C-4C38-A0D0-68FA7681E0A7) Did you correctly set the Provider?

Comment: Yes it is mentioned there. But what is this provider and where to set it?